# Magento 1.9 tierpricing calculation

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to display the actual price of what the customer saves instead of a percentage value, however I am no php expert and am kind of stumped with how to attack this problem.

Currently I have a tiered price display on my store page that looks like this.

```
<!-- Display product tier price -->
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices();
    if (count($_tierPrices) > 0):
        $_data = array();
        $_prevQty = 0;
        $_counter = 0;
        $_tierPrices = array_reverse($_tierPrices);
        foreach ($_tierPrices as $_index => $_price){
            $_counter++;
                $label = $_price['price_qty'];
                $_data[] = array('prev'=>$_prevQty,'next'=>$_price['price_qty'],'label'=>$label,'price'=>$_price['formated_price'],'save'=>$_price['savePercent']);
                $_prevQty = $_price['price_qty'];
        }
        $_data = array_reverse($_data); ?>
        <table class="price-table" id="price-tier">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Antal</th>
                    <th>Pris</th>
                    <th>Spar</th>
                </tr>
            <?php foreach ($_data as $_row): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $_row['label']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $_row['price']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $_row['save']."%"; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
<?php
    endif; ?>
```

I hope someone out there can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while looping through the tiered pricing, you can work out the ammount saved by deducting `$_price['price']` from `$_product->getFinalPrice()`
see my modified foreach loop below, which you can paste over your existing code

```
foreach ($_tierPrices as $_index => $_price){
                $_counter++;
                    $label = $_price['price_qty'];
                    $_data[] = array('prev'=>$_prevQty,'next'=>$_price['price_qty'],'label'=>$label,'price'=>$_price['formated_price'],'save'=>$_product->getFinalPrice()-$_price['price']);
                    $_prevQty = $_price['price_qty'];
            }
```

To extend on this, `$this->getProduct()` returns an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` where we can use `getFinalPrice()` to get the final price of the product.

`$this->getTierPrices()` returns a multidimensional array of the tiered price data, which contains slightly different data than if you get the tiered pricing directly from the product object, below is an example of one item within the array

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(10) {
    ["price_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["website_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["all_groups"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["cust_group"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["price"]=>
    float(341.39)
    ["price_qty"]=>
    float(5)
    ["website_price"]=>
    float(341.39)
    ["formated_price"]=>
    string(47) "£341.39"
    ["savePercent"]=>
    float(3)
    ["formated_price_incl_tax"]=>
    string(47) "£341.39"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(10){
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

**Full Code:**

```
<!-- Display product tier price -->
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices();
    if (count($_tierPrices) > 0):
        $_data = array();
        $_prevQty = 0;
        $_counter = 0;
        $_tierPrices = array_reverse($_tierPrices);
        foreach ($_tierPrices as $_index => $_price){
            $_counter++;
                $label = $_price['price_qty'];
                $_data[] = array('prev'=>$_prevQty,'next'=>$_price['price_qty'],'label'=>$label,'price'=>$_price['formated_price'],'save'=>$_product->getFinalPrice()-$_price['price']);
                $_prevQty = $_price['price_qty'];
        }
        $_data = array_reverse($_data); ?>
        <table class="price-table" id="price-tier">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Antal</th>
                    <th>Pris</th>
                    <th>Spar</th>
                </tr>
            <?php foreach ($_data as $_row): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $_row['label']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $_row['price']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $_row['save']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
<?php
    endif; ?>
```

Comment: Ive tried the above code but i still get the percentage value. is this perhaps because i echo the wrong value in the table generation ?

Comment: I will send you the full snippet of code you will need now

Comment: Please see my updated answer, i also needed to remove the '%' string after you echo $_row['save']; Basically what we have done is set $_row['save'] as the original price minus the tiered price, and removed the percentage sign which appears after this value

Comment: My version looks exactly like your version, Magento however does not seem to care one bit, i still see the percentage value with the percentage symbol even after clearing every posible cache and index, any idea whats going on here ?

Comment: After this line <?php foreach ($_data as $_row): ?> write this. `var_dump('HELLO');die;` then after clearing caches refresh the page. If it has still not changed then you are editing the wrong file or there may be a 3rd party cache in place. Do you know how to enable template path hints? you can turn them on to check if you are in the file, possible reasons its the wrong file is that it has been overridden in your theme or by an extension you have installed

Comment: i was indeed editing the wrong file thank you very much for your help much apreciated :)